# Get nested properties out in a list - using Index

Tags: linq, nosql, ravendb

I am trying to get a list of all theater names for a MVC app using RavenDB.. So I am looking to get a hold on the list of theaters names from nested objects in a ravendb document...

Sample RavenDB Document:

```
{
    "City": "NY",

    "Theaters": [
        {
            "TheaterName": "TheaterA",
            "TheaterId": "Theater/1693",
            "Description": ""               
        },
        {
            "TheaterName": "TheaterB",
            "TheaterId": "Theater/16393",
            "Description": ""               
        }
    ]
}
```

Index (GetCityTheatersIndex):

```
docs.CityTheaters
    .Select(doc => new {Theaters = doc.Theaters, City= doc.City})
```

Code:

```
 var query =  

 session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<CityTheaters>("CityTheaters/GetCityTheatersIndex");
```

How can I manipulate the variable "query" above.. to get a list of just TheaterNames.. now the above code gets me the entire document in variable "query".. I need to be able to parse out the "theater names" in the nested objects and populate to a list .. thanks for any help.

I tried something like..

query.ElementAt(1).. but that didnt get me anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a map index with field storage to do that:

```
public class CityTheaters : AbstractIndexCreationTask<City>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public CityTheaters()
    {
        Map = cities => from city in cities
                        from theater in city.Theaters
                        select new
                        {
                            theater.Name
                        };

        Store(x => x.Name, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

Later, you can query like this:

```
var results = session.Query<City, CityTheaters>()
    .AsProjection<CityTheaters.Result>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I cannot get x.Name in the Store(x=>x.Name...) line of code in the end... intellisense gives me only options.. id, City and Theaters..

Comment: If you define your index with AbstractIndexCreationTask<City, CityTheaters.Result> it normal. Don't specify the Reduced Result in AbstractIndexCreationTask generic definition. Use only  AbstractIndexCreationTask<City> as Daniel said and you'll get x.Name on Store().

Comment: Yes, I am doing only AbstractIndexCreationTask<City> .. its not giving me the x.name

Comment: I was able to get x.Name after changing the definition to public class CityTheaters : AbstractIndexCreationTask<City, CityTheaterNames>..but I am running into another issue.. I need to have the City field in the index too.. I am running a query later on this index to get all theaters for a particular city... so I need to have the city name field also indexed..

Comment: Yes, what's the problem? Just add city.Name to your index and assign another name like 'CityName' to it...